# include value with '&' in querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, url

I have to write this data in querystring:

```
  http://localhost:1256/4.market.ph.local/WEP/Add.cshtml?data=me+&+you
```

I got an error because of that symbol '&' i used.

Comment: you need to escape it

Comment: in php you would need to use `urlencode` or use `%26` for &

Comment: but i have to include it for future display

Comment: you can't use & because its a delimiter for splitting up variables eg: `foo=sdfs&bar=sdf` otherwise you wouldn't know what the individual variables were

Comment: I've changed title of you post - feel free to revert (please try keep thank you note out - accept/upvote answers as thanks intead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In c# you can use this:-

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://localhost:1256/4.market.ph.local/WEP/Add.cshtml?data=me+&+you");
```

`HttpUtility` is a part of `System.Web` and this will ensure an of the non permitted query string char are url Encoded.

Once you do this you will get something like this `http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a1256%2f4.market.ph.local%2fWEP%2fAdd.cshtml%3fdata%3dme%2b%26%2byou`

On the receiver just decode it back.

Comment: can i do it like this:
string url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://localhost:1256/4.market.ph.local/WEP/Add.cshtml?data=me+&+you").ToString();?

Comment: Yes you can. What this just does is that it makes any string url safe...

Answer (score 3):

Use `urlencode($yourstring)` or if you are hard coding it, use `%26` to represent the ampersand.

Comment: thanks. may be i'll just replace ampersand with %26 because im using C# language. ty for the info.

Comment: If it's C#, you can use `Server.HtmlEncode(string s)`